# Why is my variable decrementing?

Tags: java, android

```
while(i < numCourses){
            final int index = i;

            //Create a Dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input_dialog);
            TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
            textView.setText("" + i);
            dialog.show();

            //Button for the dialog.
            Button b = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Get input Course Numbers, numCourses times
                    EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText2); //EditText
                    String getInput = editText.getText().toString();             //String input
                    try {
                        courseNumbers[index] = Integer.parseInt(getInput);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + courseNumbers[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }catch (Exception ex){}

                    //Dismiss dialog
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            i++;
        }
```

This is what my variable int = i shows up in the Dialog, suppose numCourses was 4:

```
3
2
1
0
```

My question is why is decrementing backwards, instead of incrementing forward from 0 to 3. And to receive an array of inputs from a dialog, how can I efficiently ask for input, numCourses times? Instead of me having a while loop and incrememnting i, which I feel is not efficient.

Comment: Because you're stacking 4 `Dialog`s, with the newer one on top of the last, so 3 ends up on top, and as you dismiss them, you count down to 0. That `while` loop doesn't pause when you show a `Dialog`. All of them pop up at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not using loop, after each input has been clicked, then show the next dialog.

```
public void showCourseDialog(final int i, final int numCourses){
final int index = i;

        //Create a Dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.input_dialog);
        TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        textView.setText("" + i);
        dialog.show();

        //Button for the dialog.
        Button b = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Get input Course Numbers, numCourses times
                EditText editText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.editText2); //EditText
                String getInput = editText.getText().toString();             //String input
                try {
                    courseNumbers[index] = Integer.parseInt(getInput);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + courseNumbers[index], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }catch (Exception ex){}

                //Dismiss dialog
                dialog.dismiss();

               if(i < numCourses)
                  showCourseDialog(++i, numCourses);
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: There was an error at showCourseDialog(++i, numCourses); because is a final value. So I created a local int variable equal to i, and pre-incremented that instead